# Device soft-bricked after flashing Xposed ;-;

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

Newbie here! I rooted my phone, (Samsung Galaxy Note 3 SM-N900) and I'm trying to get Xposed working. After flashing Xposed*.zip, my device is just stuck on the "SAMSUNG" screen. Do you guys/gals know any way to install Xposed for my phone?

Any help would be appreciated! :D

Comment: Maybe you flashed a version that's incompatible with your phone. Some phones need a specific version of Xposed (be it version or CPU architecture). There's an uninstaller zip available. Just flash that and try another version.

Comment: Do you have custom recovery TWRP/CWM? If yes then search for uninstaller on place where you downloaded xposed from, and simply flash it from recovery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to boot your device in download mode, you can do that by:

1. Switch off your device completely.
2. Press and hold Volume Down, Home and Power, all at the same time.
3. Release all buttons when you see the Warning! screen
4. Press the Volume Up button to confirm that you want to boot Download Mode

Then, download Kies from [here](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/app/kies), after you install it, connect your phone to your computer and you should get a message from Kies, ignore it.

On the Kies menu bar, click Tools and then click Firmware Upgrade and Intialisation

Enter the information it requires (Usually, you can find them at the back of your phone) and then Kies will factory reset your phone.

To install Xposed, visit [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/unofficial-xposed-samsung-lollipop-t3113463) link.

Comment: Np, please make sure you mark the answer as correct so other people can see it too.